# Are questions regarding carnivorous plants within the scope of this site?

Tags: discussion, scope

Nowadays,

carnivorous plants have become a popular pet for many.

Some of them sold as pets are -

1. tropical pitcher plants
2. pitcher plants
3. venus flytrap
4. drosera capensis
5. sundews
6. trumpet pitchers

They are also available online from major e-commerce sites.

So, my question is -

Will questions regarding *pet carnivorous plants* fall within the scope of the site?

Answer (score 8):

In my opinion, no. They are not animals.

Comment: I guess this means question about [Pet Rocks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pet_Rock) are out as well.

Comment: @JamesJenkins hmmmm, tricky. Now I'm reconsidering my answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

I think no, since it is not the best place for questions about 'non-animals'.  Posters are more likely to get useful answers (that is, answers from users with lots of relevant experience), by posting about plants on Gardening and Landscaping SE.